# SQL Statement calling object_id with Like AND Like - Not Or

Tags: mysql, sql

As always thanks for your help in advance. I've been stuck on this one for a few days and can't get my head around it. Last ditch effort posting up here.

What i'm trying to achieve -
Grab all object_id MATCHING BOTH 'house' AND 'nightclub'

This involves 3 tables being joined to reach

```
WP_2_TERMS
--------------------------------------------------------
term_id    |    name    |    slug    |   term_group   |
  3          nightclub     nightclub        0
  41           house        house-3         0
--------------------------------------------------------

WP_2_TAXONOMY
-------------------------------------------------------
term_taxonomy_id    |    term_id    |    taxonomy    | 
         3                  3            category
         42                 41            Music
-------------------------------------------------------

WP_2_TERM_RELATIONSHIPS
-------------------------------------------------------
object_id    |    term_taxonomy_id    |    term_order    | 
    13                   4                     0
    13                   42                    0
    65                   3                     0
    65                   42                    0
    111                  3                    0

-------------------------------------------------------
```

So ideally the sql would output just the object_id 65
but at the moment it returns 0 rows

So far this is what I have. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong, and care to explain please?

```
SELECT `rel`.`object_id`
    FROM `wp_2_term_relationships` as `rel`
    INNER JOIN `wp_2_term_taxonomy` as `tax` ON rel.term_taxonomy_id = tax.term_taxonomy_id
    LEFT JOIN `wp_2_terms` as `terms` ON tax.term_id = terms.term_id 
    LEFT JOIN `wp_2_terms` as `terms2` ON tax.term_id = terms2.term_id 
    WHERE terms.name LIKE '%house% AND terms2.name LIKE '%nightclub%'
```

Also, yes I know this could be done with wp_query but I'm migrating away from Wordpress so unfortunately for the moment this is the best solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is that even though you are joining the table `wp_2_terms` twice, you are joining to the same column (`tax.term_id`), therefore `terms.name` will always be the same as `terms2.name`, and since these will be the same they cannot simultaneously be `nightclub` and `house`.

The standard approach for this is to use `GROUP BY/HAVING`:

```
SELECT  rel.object_id
FROM    wp_2_term_relationships AS rel
        INNER JOIN wp_2_term_taxonomy AS tax 
            ON rel.term_taxonomy_id = tax.term_taxonomy_id
        INNER JOIN wp_2_terms AS terms
            ON tax.term_id = terms.term_id 
WHERE   terms.Name IN ('house', 'nightclub')
GROUP BY rel.object_id
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT terms.Name) > 1;
```

If using `LIKE` is mandatory rather than simply equals, you can rewrite as:

```
SELECT  rel.object_id
FROM    wp_2_term_relationships AS rel
        INNER JOIN wp_2_term_taxonomy AS tax 
            ON rel.term_taxonomy_id = tax.term_taxonomy_id
        INNER JOIN wp_2_terms AS terms
            ON tax.term_id = terms.term_id 
WHERE   terms.Name LIKE '%house%'
OR      terms.Name LIKE '%nightclub%'
GROUP BY rel.object_id
HAVING  COUNT(CASE WHEN terms.Name LIKE '%house%' THEN 1 END) >= 1
AND     COUNT(CASE WHEN terms.Name LIKE '%nightclub%' THEN 1 END) >= 1;
```

Comment: THANKYOU!! I appreciate you taking the time to not only answer my question but explaining the method! +1

Comment: Also @GarethD if I wanted to run this backwards, as in I have the object_ID but wanted to find the terms.Name how would I reorganise this? - Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be enough.

```
SELECT `rel`.`object_id`
FROM 
    `wp_2_term_relationships` as `rel`
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    `wp_2_term_taxonomy` as `tax` ON rel.term_taxonomy_id = tax.term_taxonomy_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    `wp_2_terms` as `terms` ON tax.term_id = terms.term_id 
WHERE 
    terms.name LIKE '%house%' 
AND 
    terms.name LIKE '%nightclub%'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @kmas but still it returns ZERO rows :/

Comment: Just to be sure, wp_2_term_taxonomy and WP_2_TAXONOMY are the same table...?

Comment: They are different tables. Overall there are 3 tables. wp_2_terms - wp_2_taxonomy - wp_2_terms_relationships

Comment: Just look at the description of your tables... ;)